# Recursive method to calculate log

Tags: java, recursion

I did the following to calculate recursive logarithm:(b is the base of log here)

```java
int log(int b, int n) {
  if (n/b == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return log(b, n/b) + 1;
  }
}
```

However, it's wrong.I'm doing it from the openDSA interactive platform.The original question is the following:

> For function "log", write the missing base case condition and the recursive call. This function computes the log of "n" to the base "b". As an example: log 8 to the base 2 equals 3 since 8 = 2*2*2. We can find this by dividing 8 by 2 until we reach 1, and we count the number of divisions we made. You should assume that "n" is exactly "b" to some integer power.

```java
int log(int b, int n) {
  if /* Missing base case condition */ {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return /* Missing a Recursive case action */;
  }
}
```

My code is incorrect.I'm getting infinite recursion.

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Is the problem because you have `return log(int b, int n/b)+1;` rather than `return log(b, n/b)+1;`?

Comment: What is the point of doing this calculation using integers?

Comment: I added the full question from openDSA, please see my edited question.

Comment: Yes, but what if it's the log base 2 of 17, what is the expected output?

Comment: " You should assume that "n" is exactly "b" to some integer power." --from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format **MUST** be like this:

```
int log(int b, int n ) {
    if <<enter base case>> {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return <<enter action case>> ;
    }
}
```

Then the safest method (that I can come up with) would be:

```
int log(int b, int n ) {
    if (n <= b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return log(b, n/b)+1 ;

    }
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something here but that doesn't look correct. log(2,6), log(2,7), log(2,8), log(2,9) all return 3 with your log function. See https://ideone.com/XrEYOr

Comment: @AmirGonnen "You should assume that "n" is exactly "b" to some integer power." --from the question. You are right that the last sentence is slightly misleading... Removed.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution in my opinion would be

```
int log(int b, int n ) {
    if (b > n) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + log(b, n/b);
    }
}
```

This returns the log base b of n rounded down to an integer, and has more consistency with inexact results than the other answer.

e.g. log(2,6)=2 ; log(2,7)=2 ; log(2,8)=3 ; log(2,9)=3

Though, it still doesn't handle things like b < 2 or cases where the result would be negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
int log(int b, int n ) {
if (b == 1) {
    return b;
} else if (n == 1) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1 + log(b, n/b);
}
}
```